# Problems with composer manager on windows

Tags: drush, composer

I'm trying to use the dev version of openlayers which requires composer mananger. I can successfully install the module, and the module creates a json file with my packages inside my sites/default/files/composer folder. The problem I have is that the drush composer install command isn't recognized by drush. I get the drush error

```
The drush command 'composer install' could not be found.  Run `drush      
cache-clear drush` to clear the commandfile cache if you have
installed new extensions.
```

not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: There's no drush command, you need to run composer itself - have you read [the documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2405811)?

Comment: Not completely, just what I thought I needed to get up an running. When I just run "composer install" I get the error "could not open input file: composer.phar" which I don't understand because I used composer to install drush. I might have to do with my composer install being global vs within the Drupal root, but that should t be an issue

Comment: Yep sounds like a path issue. Best to read the docs rather than assume, there's a specific set of thing that need to happen for this to work

Comment: @clive #1 On linux I use `drush composer-manager install <name>` or `drush composer-manager install <name> --no-dev`. That runs composer through composer manager and on behalf of the site. But I am not sure about windows. I would assume it is the same.

Comment: That's probably the OP's issue @Neograph742, they're running a slightly different command. Worth putting that in is an answer I'd say